# Emulate non-number numpad keys?

Tags: interface

On my tablet I don't have a numpad, so I have enabled *Emulate Numpad* in the user preferences.  This allows the normal keyboard numbers to perform the functions their respective numpad number buttons would normally do.

However, this only emulates the numpad *numbers*, not the other buttons it has such as <kbd>`.`</kbd> (center view on selected) or <kbd>`/`</kbd> (local view).  Is there any way I can emulate these (and all the other numpad keys) if I don't have a numpad?

Comment: When *Emulate Numpad* enabled it's possible to use `Back Slash` button as `Numpad /` for Local View. However this doesn't seem to work for period button etc.

Comment: You could enable pie-menus and use the Q-Key (if possible). For *local view* there is a sub menu called *More*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned the <kbd>\</kbd> is already set for local view, the <kbd>=</kbd> (+ without shift) and <kbd>-</kbd> are also set to replace the numpad <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> (for zoom in/out). For others you most likely want to setup some custom keys.

In the Input preferences you can search for key-bindings containing `numpad` and then adjust the ones you want to use by clicking the key display and choosing another key. The issue is finding a key that isn't used or that *you* don't make use of, then save your settings so they are always available.

[image: input settings]

You may find that the <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> can be used as they are shortcuts to brush size when sculpting/painting where <kbd>F</kbd> is more well known. Also <kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>4</kbd>,<kbd>6</kbd>,<kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>9</kbd> are less used by many people.

Comment: I did not know you could search by key bindings and I didn't know what the actual command name was (*View Selected*) so I couldn't find it on the list.  Thanks!