# How can I enlarge selection without numpad?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

The  command <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> makes the selection larger by adding loops to the selection.

The example of mesh:

[image: example image of mesh]

I want to select 3 loops more. At the moment I do it with Circle Select tool via <kbd>C</kbd> but I want to do it faster.

Here is the desired selection:

[image: example image of desired selection]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45911/emulate-non-number-numpad-keys and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-emulate-a-number-pad-and-3-button-mouse

Comment: Why don't you make a Vertex Group and add those verts to it so you can quickly select them again later without using *any* selection tools?

Comment: Actually, [Crtl]+[Numpad +] is quite fast (and intuitive) to do... what would be your preferred command? As Mr Zak commented above, you can customize commands, the only problem being is: there are already so many command shortcuts... it's crowded. Also could pie menus be another way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>numpad +</kbd> three times. :)

Comment: I don't have numpad. I have found other commands. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Okay, sorry. I didn't realize that in the title you asked how without a numpad. I was just thinking of the end of your question where you were wondering a fast way. I'm glad you got it. :)