# Period key does nothing on Mac keyboard without numberpad

Tags: interface

I have an iMac with a wireless keyboard with no number pad. I am using Blender 2.78.

In one of the absolute beginner videos it says that if I turn on 'Emulate Numpad' then the keyboard's normal period `'.'` key should function to re-centre the view to the selected object (after I have used shift and middle mouse to pan across).

But when I press the period key it doesn't seem to do anything.

I have checked in `User Preferences > Input` and I can see Outliner > Show Active has a mapping to `'.'`

[image: User Preferences Key Mappings]

Is something set up wrong or am I misunderstanding what this key is supposed to do?

Comment: The shortcut shown on the screenshot is set up for the [Outliner editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html), while you want it to be in the 3d Viewport editor; in the latter Period button used for setting pivot point to 3D Cursor so most likely it still is the same. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45911/emulate-non-number-numpad-keys, looks like you need to setup some custom shortcuts to make Period button work like Numpad Period.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have managed to sort it. Though I don't understand why there are more than one key bindings with the same name 'View selected'. Is that just multiple key bindings for the same action?

Comment: Actions and shortcuts for them differ depending on the [editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/index.html) where this action is used in. So while it might seem there are multiple key bindings for the same action they are different for Blender because are used in different contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell just by looking at it, but it's set to *Numpad* period. Remap it to regular period and you should be fine. (Emulate Numpad doesn't change this one.)

Comment: Thanks. I saw that in Blender 2.9 it now says "Numpad ." by default which makes it clearer